# How to restart the service when application closed?

Tags: android, service, notifications

I am using the service for sending notifications every 30 sec. When my application is in background mode it is working fine. Every notification receives properly. But when I kill/close my application the service stops and I am not receiving any notification.

Anybody have an idea on how to run the service when application is closed or killed?

here is my manifest file`
   ``

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MainService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
         >
    </service>
    <service android:name=".NewService" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Comment: Kill from recent apps?

Comment: yes i am kill the application from recent application

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue your service even after killing application from Recent app's list, set `stopWithTask` as `false` in manifest:

```
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

And your Service should be sticky.

```
@Override
public final int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStarCommand(): Received id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    return START_STICKY; // run until explicitly stopped.
}
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842675/continue-service-even-if-application-is-cleared-from-recent-app) question for all details.

And if you want to perform some additional action when application gets removed from recent list, you can override method [onTaskRemoved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27498630/1777090)

Hope this helps.

Comment: its working fine but when i click on the recent application button my application directly open i do not want to open my application like this

Comment: You click on recent app or remove it? What do you want to do if user opens app from recent app list? Put your code in onResume of that activity

Comment: now my recent button just open my application not show the other application  list

Comment: What you are saying is not very clear. Please explain properly.

Comment: when i click on recent apps button(right side of home button) then instead of the recent apps list, my app is getting open up. otherwise the functionality is working fine with your given code. 
is it clear now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70783/discussion-between-user3459071-and-flameprincess).

Comment: have you find the solution