# How to get notified about app being completely closed

Tags: flutter

I need to take an action when my app gets destroyed. I tried to use `WidgetsBindingObserver` and `WillPopScope` so far but none of them is invoked in case user removes the app from launcher's recent apps. Is there a way to execute some code before app is completely gone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter detect killing off the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074265/flutter-detect-killing-off-the-app)

Answer (score 2):

As far is I know for now, there is no way in Flutter. But I know a native way in Android (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27498582/9169159))

You can implement this in your MainActivity or so, see [this how to call Android/iOS code from Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

I don't know how to do in iOS, but that could be a bit more difficult due to iOS's different app resource handling etc.

Also, it could be a nice idea for a plugin/package. So developers, go ahead ;)