# how to detect if app is closed but not if the phone is closed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to detect if app is closed or suspended but not when the phone is closed. I have used **AppLifecycleState** but it detected app close and phone close as the same thing

---

I'm making a chat app.

for example:

if app closed close the chat
but
if phone is closed nothing will happen and the chat will remain as it is.

Comment: Try looking at [How to get notified about app being completely closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417470/how-to-get-notified-about-app-being-completely-closed).